# Typeahead field is not displaying non-english characters in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using typeahead field in angular js which is displaying data consumed from a web-service. The non-english character 'ô' is not being displayed correctly in UI. It is being displayed as '?'. How can I enable the typeahead to display non-english characters correctly.

Comment: When you say it's not being displayed, do you mean even when you directly type it into the UI, or just when it's loading preexisting data from the database?